# Vaadin 24 resync issue

Tags: vaadin, push, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

From time to time I may see the following PUSH error in the logs:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unexpected message id from the client. Expected sync id: 117, got 118. more details logged on DEBUG level.
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:310) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha3.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:114) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha3.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha3.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1529) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha3.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:398) ~[flow-server-24.1.0.alpha3.jar!/:24.1.0.alpha3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:106) ~[vaadin-spring-24.1.0.alpha3.jar!/:na]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:258) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToServlet(ServletInitialHandler.java:193) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:186) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:136) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:99) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:178) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:547) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar!/:6.0.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:172) ~[undertow-websockets-jsr-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:151) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:129) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:181) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/:6.0.7]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101) ~[undertow-servlet-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393) ~[undertow-core-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859) ~[undertow-core-2.3.4.Final.jar!/:2.3.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18) ~[jboss-threads-3.5.0.Final.jar!/:3.5.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513) ~[jboss-threads-3.5.0.Final.jar!/:3.5.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538) ~[jboss-threads-3.5.0.Final.jar!/:3.5.0.Final]
    at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282) ~[xnio-api-3.8.8.Final.jar!/:3.8.8.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

What could be the cause of this?

**UPDATED**

With DEBUG enabled I got the following:

```
2023-04-20T17:12:20.587+03:00 DEBUG 1539148 --- [XNIO-1 task-4] c.v.f.s.communication.ServerRpcHandler   : Unexpected message id from the client. Expected sync id: 0, got 1. Message start: { type: publishedEventHandler node: 120.0 feature: null } { type: publishedEventHandler node: 48.0 feature: null } { type: channel node: 1.0 feature: null } 
2023-04-20T17:12:20.588+03:00 DEBUG 1539148 --- [XNIO-1 task-9] c.v.f.server.communication.UidlWriter    : * Creating response to client
2023-04-20T17:12:20.589+03:00 ERROR 1539148 --- [XNIO-1 task-4]
```

Comment: "more details logged on DEBUG level" have you tried it? Is there a log/stacktrace before or after?

Comment: I'm going to enable DEBUG on the prod. Will update here

Comment: btw, what kind of logs it is better to enable  - `logging.level.com.vaadin=DEBUG` or something else?

Comment: The debug logging happens right before the exception.  So if you want to log the least amount, the logger is `com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler`

Comment: I was able to catch it with debug. I updated my question with additional info

Comment: added issue: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16664

Comment: I have the same issue with Vaadin 24.2.x. How do you resolve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I still may see this issue from time to time